# States of matter

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am curious what are the physical factors in nature that some atoms exist as solids while others as liquid gases etc. Why some atoms and molecules have large interatomic distances and why some have less interatomic distances?

Answer (score 3):

> Why some atoms and molecules have large interatomic distances and why
>   some have less interatomic distances?

The short answer is it is because of the amount of internal potential energy (i.e., potential energy at the atomic/molecular level) that a substance possesses, which is a in turn a function of the interatomic/intermolecular separation.  Consequently for a given substance, the substance has the lowest internal potential energy in the solid phase, and the greatest in the gaseous phase.

To explain further in terms of phase transition:

Whether a substance is a gas, liquid, or solid depends on the temperature and/or pressure of the substance. For example all gases, with the exception of helium, can solidify if the temperature is low enough. Helium can also solidify but it requires, in addition, applied pressure even at temperatures approaching absolute zero.

A substance possesses internal energy which is the sum of its kinetic and potential energy at the atomic and molecular level. Its internal kinetic energy is due to the translational, rotational an vibrational motions of the atoms and molecules. Its internal potential energy is a function of the intermolecular/interatomic distances. There are attractive intermolecular forces. In order to separate the molecules/atoms energy is required thereby increasing the potential energy of the molecules/atoms.This is somewhat analogous to the energy (work) required to separate a mass from the surface of the earth giving the mass gravitational potential energy.

In order to change the state of matter of a substance energy must be supplied or extracted from the substance, normally in the form of heat, thereby increasing or decreasing the internal molecular distances (increasing or decreasing, respectively, the internal potential energy of the substance). For example, to convert a solid to a liquid one must first raise the temperature of the solid until it reaches its "melting" point by supplying heat. Raising the temperature increases the internal kinetic energy. When the melting point is reached, a transition from solid to liquid phase occurs as the molecules separate. This generally occurs at constant temperature so the internal kinetic energy essentially remains the same, but the separation of the molecules increases increasing the internal potential energy. Thus the heat supplied (called latent heat of fusion) results in an increase in the internal potential energy of the substance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer @Bob!! I know this is an old question, but can you please tell me if gases have the most potential energy as compared to liquids which in turn have more potential energy than solids? Is this correct? Thanks....

Comment: @NatashaJ Gas as a saturated vapor has more positive potential energy than than a liquid which, in turn, has more positive potential energy than a solid because potential energy starts out being negative and gets more positive transitioning from a solid to a gas. But it eventually becomes zero for a gas when the molecules are far enough apart. That's because the intermolecular forces between gas molecules approaches zero.

Comment: So, potential energy of solids is negative and potential energy of gases is zero. The potential energy of solids is negative due to greater intermolecular forces of attraction. Is this correct?

Comment: +1 I am impressed by the explanation. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

It  is all mainly a question of temperature.  On Earth, water is usually a liquid, but on Titan and Mars it is a solid, hard as rock, while the liquid water which once existed on Venus soon became a gas, and the gas, with the aid of volcanic sulphur dioxide, soon became clouds of sulphurous acid. On Earth, lead, sodium, potassium and a number of other metals are solids, but on Venus, in pure form, they would be liquids or gases. On Venus, pure mercury, caesium  and some other metals would be gasses. On Earth, nitrogen is a gas, but on Pluto it is a liquid, and sometimes a solid. CO2 is a gas in some parts of the solar system and a solid in others, but so far as I am aware, in no place is it a liquid, which would require special conditions of pressure and temperature.

Comment: *It is all mainly a question of temperature.* Don't you mean temperature and pressure, as you say in your final sentence?

Comment: FWIW, [liquid carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_carbon_dioxide) can exist in the temperature range -56.6 °C to 31.1 °C, but the pressure must be at least 5.1 atm (at the low temperature limit), and not too high. There's a phase diagram on the linked page. It's not inconceivable that those conditions exist underground somewhere in the solar system.

Answer (score 0):

States of matter are the distinct forms matter can exist, there are four in everyday life, solid, liquid, gas and plasma.

There are many intermediate states, though, like liquid crystals, and some can only exist under extreme conditions (Bose Einstein Condensate, for extreme temperature, neutron degenerate matter for extreme density, and quark gluon plasma for extreme energy).

> > Historically, the distinction is made based on qualitative differences in properties. Matter in the solid state maintains a fixed volume and shape, with component particles (atoms, molecules or ions) close together and fixed into place. Matter in the liquid state maintains a fixed volume, but has a variable shape that adapts to fit its container. Its particles are still close together but move freely. Matter in the gaseous state has both variable volume and shape, adapting both to fit its container. Its particles are neither close together nor fixed in place. Matter in the plasma state has variable volume and shape, and contains neutral atoms as well as a significant number of ions and electrons, both of which can move around freely.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter

Now your question can be interpreted in two ways:

1. What decides whether a certain matter takes a certain state under certain conditions:

> > The state or phase of a given set of matter can change depending on pressure and temperature conditions

Now here are some extreme cases (where temperature, density or energy can create a special case of matter):

1. temperature (one extreme case here is BEC)
2. density (one extreme case here is neutron degenerate matter)
3. energy (one extreme case here is quark gluon plasma)

> > Solids can be transformed into liquids by melting, and liquids can be transformed into solids by freezing. Solids can also change directly into gases through the process of sublimation, and gases can likewise change directly into solids through deposition.
> >     When a solid is heated above its melting point, it becomes liquid, given that the pressure is higher than the triple point of the substance.
> >     A liquid may be converted to a gas by heating at constant pressure to the boiling point, or else by reducing the pressure at constant temperature.
> >     A gas is usually converted to a plasma in one of two ways, e.g., either from a huge voltage difference between two points, or by exposing it to extremely high temperatures. Heating matter to high temperatures causes electrons to leave the atoms, resulting in the presence of free electrons. This creates a so-called partially ionised plasma. At very high temperatures, such as those present in stars, it is assumed that essentially all electrons are "free", and that a very high-energy plasma is essentially bare nuclei swimming in a sea of electrons. This forms the so-called fully ionised plasma.

[image]

2. What QM description do these four states of matter have that distinguishes them:

   1. in solids, atoms are so closely packed together, forces between them are strong, the atoms cannot freely move but vibrate. We use the expression lattice structure.
   2. liquid is a nearly incompressible fluid, that transforms to the shape of the container but keeps its volume. Intermolecular forces are important but the molecules have enough degrees of freedom to move relative to each other. The volume is usually greater then solid, except water(and some other matter).
   3. gas is a compressible fluid. Not only will it take the shape of the container but it will expand to fill it. Molecules have enough kinetic energy so that the effect of intermolecular forces is small. The average distance is much greater then the size of the molecules.
   4. plasma does not have a definite shape or volume, but unlike gases, plasmas are EM conductive.